# How to set individual IndexedDb storage per user email

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, asynchronous, indexeddb

I am making a react application where a user can create some data in their own profile and later view it. I am saving this data in IndexedDB using localForage. The problem is due to IndexedDB's design, an IndexedDB store saves data according to the domain. And I have multiple users logging in and creating data. I am using firebase and I can get user email by using onAuthStateChange method. I need to create a store for each account in IndexedDB. I tried doing it but I am stuck with running async and sync code in a correct way. Here's my code where I am creating an IndexedDb instance -

```
import localforage from 'localforage';

let totalCardsData = localforage.createInstance({
    name: 'totalCardsData',
    storeName: 'cards',
});

export { totalCardsData };
```

Using this I can create only 1 store called 'totalCardsData'. Here I tried making a dynamic name for the object.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import localforage from 'localforage';
import initFirebase from '../utils/auth/initFirebase';

initFirebase();

let userEmail = '';
let totalCardsData;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        userEmail = user.email;
    }
});

totalCardsData = localforage.createInstance({
    // name: 'totalCardsData',
    name: `${userEmail}`,
    storeName: 'cards',
});

export { totalCardsData };
```

onAuthStateChanged is an asynchronous method. So I am getting an empty string for `${userEmail}` because onAuthStateChanged finishes it's execution after rest of the code have been finished executing.

I want to run totalCardsData after the onAuthStateChanged has finished execution. So that I can get userEmail string.

Comment: You have multiple users on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. I have more than one users on the same machine.

Comment: You need to wait to create the instance until the auth state changed. You are not waiting right now.

Comment: Yes. That's what the issue is. I don't know how to pause code execution till auth state changes. Here's the last part of my question - I want to run totalCardsData after the onAuthStateChanged has finished execution. So that I can get userEmail string.

Comment: you're trying to statically export a dynamic value. you cannot do this. you have to only call localForage.createInstance from the auth event callback handler.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. Auth event finished execution after all the code has been executed. So no matter what I do, the export exports an undefined value; Because export happens before I populate localforage instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

1. Seperate firebase onAuthStateChange (ex: `module1`) and localstorage creation logic(Ex: `module2`) in two different modules, import both in parent file.
2. Write a method which takes userEmail as argument and retuns localstorage instance in `module2` and export that method(ex: `createLocalStorageInstance`).
3. Generate a custom event and emit it from onAuthStateChange and listen to it in parent file and from there call `createLocalStorageInstance`.

This should work.

Comment: I wrapped my createLocalInstance into a function and took email as a parameter of that function.And then exported that function with return value of createLocalStorage. So I didn't do exactly what you told but your answer gave me idea. So I am marking your answer correct.